# Add styles to Yesod forms

Tags: forms, authentication, twitter-bootstrap, haskell, yesod

I am trying to use an authentication plugin for Yesod:  yesod-auth-account.  It provides a default form to use, and I am hoping to add some bootstrap/template specific styles to it.  If I use a custom form, I'll have to override a lot of methods.

This is especially pressing since I'd like to reuse the form in different display contexts (in a navbar, next to the sign up form, etc).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You could wrap default email `AuthPlugin`:

```
authEmailCustom :: YesodAuthEmail m => AuthPlugin m
authEmailCustom =
    AuthPlugin "email" (apDispatch authEmail) $ \tm ->
        [whamlet|
<form method="post" action="@{tm loginR}">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    <a href="@{tm registerR}">I don't have an account
|]
```

Just substitute your styled form. Then use it instead of default one:

```
instance YesodAuth App where
    ...
    authPlugins _ = [authEmailCustom]
```

Hope this helps.